# What am I pointing at?

Tags: lateral-thinking, story

I go into a store and point. I say "How much for 1?"
The storeowner replies "20 cents".

I then ask "So, how much is 12?" His answer: "40 cents".

I decide "Please could I have 112".
"That will be 60 cents please", replies the owner.

What was I pointing at?

Comment: This is a classic lateral thinking puzzle that's been around for a looong time and can be found all over the web (e.g. [here](http://themathmompuzzles.blogspot.com/2013/03/new-house-puzzle.html), [here](https://www.facebook.com/ultimateriddles/posts/a-man-went-to-a-hardware-store-to-buy-items-for-his-house-1-would-cost-25-12-wou/641531952604845/), [here](https://riddlesbrainteasers.com/cost-household-hardware/) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/riddles/comments/q2kg48/whats_the_answer_to_this_riddle/)) - this should probably be mentioned in the question...

Answer (score 17):

You were pointing at

> brass digits for your house number. Each digit is 20 cents.

Answer (score 2):

> Each digit value is 20 cents, so for 1 is 20 cents (because the number is just one digit) for 12 is 40 because the number has two digits and for 112 is 60 because the number has three digits.

Comment: Welcome! Consider putting your answer in spoiler tags using ">! ".